# Adding mandatory arguments to optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

What I want to do is very basic, yet I could not find how to do it when browsing various doc/tutorial. Maybe my whole approach is wrong.

For example, this works fine, allowing user to perform action a or action b

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-do-a","--do_a",action="store_true",help="perform action a")
parser.add_argument("-do-b","--do_b",action="store_true",help="perform action b")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now let's say action b requires to be given a file name. How may I enforce this ? 
A non correct solution to give a better idea of what I would like to do:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-do-a","--do_a",action="store_true",help="perform action a")
parser.add_argument("-do-b","--do_b",action="store_true",help="perform action b on file","--file",required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Your proposal doesn't make much sense. If you need a parameter for a switch, then why not just make it an optional value, and test for its presence? I.e `if do_b is None` then don't perform `b`, else perform b using its value. Or if your real example is more complicated, you need to perform check manually. It would make sense if you had like 3 params. Or if you wanna do something `git` style, you gotta use subparsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can define `file` as an argument to option `-do-b` like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-do-a", "--do_a", action="store_true",help="perform action a")
parser.add_argument("-do-b", "--do_b", action="store", type=str, nargs=1, default=False, help="perform action b on file")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`args.do_b` will be either `False` or a list with a single string item.

Alternatively, you could use [sub-parsers](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) but this is more complex and unnecessary in your case. It would be necessary if the `file` argument was optional for option `do_b`.